# Raspberry pi 4 crashes when opening VLC, Openshot, or RPI-Imager

Tags: raspbian, hardware, vlc

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 model B 4gb, and any time I open the apps stated above, the window opens, it doesn't display anything, the window is super huge and crashes. Multiple times has this question been asked [Like this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120833/pi4-crashes-when-running-any-qt-apps-like-rpi-imager-vlc-obs?newreg=f166b125783146c288407adca8ee0afc), but I REQUEST ANSWERS! Please, if anyone can help us, I would greatly appreciate it. PLEASE, even if it's something, I need to know.

**VLC:**
Opening anything in vlc will stop the computer entirely, and after a few seconds the vlc icon is the only thing that displays on screen, no input works after that.

**OPENSHOT:**
Openshot opens, but the window is so big it usually crashes the computer. I can't get to any menus or change it in the config files either.

**RPI-IMAGER:** This is the most annoying one of all honestly, because it's the one that made me come to this website and ask this eternal question. I click on the app to open it and nothing happens. Same scenario as openshot, but the thing crashes before it displays *anything!*

This is extremely aggravating and I seriously would love any help I can get, thank you.

Comment: what is gpu_mem set to? is v3d-fkms-vc4 enabled? have you changed anything in config.txt or cmdline.txt?

Comment: I haven't changed anything in cmdline, and gpu_mem isn't a thing

Comment: gpu_mem isn't a thing? I didn't realise the pi4 didn't use that setting, I must be so ignorant - and what about config.txt, did you change anything in there?

Comment: I played with the clock settings a bit but this problem has existed for months before I overclocked. That's all

Comment: fair enough, so what is your gpu_mem setting, is v3d-fkms-vc4 enabled - I don't know what standard config.txt looks like (mine is far from standard), that's why I'm asking about those settings

Comment: I think I know what you mean by gpu_mem, and from what i get it is at 76. and, dtoverlay=vc4.fkms-v3d is what i see in config

Comment: *I REQUEST ANSWERS!* is how you talk to the paid customer support, not to volunteers on a community website. Tone it down a notch!

Comment: First, I would try upping gpu_mem to 128 or even 256 ... second, try without `dtoverlay=vc4.fkms-v3d` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Check power delivery - both voltage and current. I had few issues with using low-quality usb cables, like Pi suddenly resetting itseld etc.. Check voltage on 5V GPIO.